Stop Proxmox 8.2.2 instance from sending email for its crontab entries
I have an instance of Proxmox 8.2.2.
I want to STOP email being sent for the crontab entries for the root user on this server.
I have a cronjob running as root in the console on that Proxmox 8.2.2. instance that looks like this:
MAILTO='nobody@nowhere.com'
* * * * * /sbin/ntpdate -u 192.168.10.1 >/dev/null 2>&1

I have also tried stopping cron emails by doing this
MAILTO='nobody@nowhere.com'
* * * * * /sbin/ntpdate -u 192.168.10.1 >/dev/null 2>&1 || true

and this
MAILTO=''
* * * * * /sbin/ntpdate -u 192.168.10.1 >/dev/null 2>&1 || true

and this
MAILTO=
* * * * * /sbin/ntpdate -u 192.168.10.1 >/dev/null 2>&1 || true

And, in the Proxmox GUI, I have changed Datacenter -> Users -> Edit User -> root@pam -> E-Mail to "nobody@nowhere.com" as well.
I'm still getting email on my Outlook instance on my desktop PC from the above cronjob on this physical Proxmox server every single minute.
How do I stop the emails from the Proxmox machine's crontab permanently - e. g. in Debian?
I get this email every 60 seconds on my desktop PC:
Subject: Cron <root@proxmox> /sbin/ntpdate -u 192.168.1.10
Message: 

CLOCK: time stepped by 0.995971
2024-05-12 19:19:02.405469 (+0200) +0.995971 +/- 0.000728 172.16.1.9 s1 no-leap

This is what I want to stop...
I did initially when installing Proxmox specify my email address correctly. Big mistake.
Thanks
